# Using Html.DropDownList helper with a ViewBag list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the code:

```
@using SSA.Models;

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.ToString()</h2>

@{
    using(Html.BeginForm()){
        List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach(Item c in ViewBag.Items)
        {
            SelectListItem i = new SelectListItem();
            i.Text = c.Name.ToString();
            i.Value = c.SiteID.ToString();
            selectList.Add(new SelectListItem());
        }
        Html.DropDownList("Casinos", new SelectList(selectList,"Value","Text"));
    }
}
```

The list, selectList, on breakpoint shows it has 108 values. What renders is an empty form. No run time errors.

Note: I know using the ViewBag for this is not the best method. This is throw-away code and I'd just like to understand why it is not rendering the dropdown.

Comment: Why don't you construct the ViewBag on the server side. Then, you can simply refer to it in the dropdown. 
ViewBag.Casinos= new SelectList(Your IEnumerableList Here, "Values", "Values");
Then, your view will look something like this
Html.DropDownList("Casinos", String.Empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
   IEnumerable<MyItemType> CDrop = ViewBag.Cat;


        List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var c in CDrop)
        {
            SelectListItem i = new SelectListItem();
            i.Text = c.Decsription.ToString();
            i.Value = c.TypeID.ToString();
            selectList.Add(i);
        }

}

}

    then some where in your view. 

    @Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(selectList, "Value","Text"));
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not rendering because it's all inside a razor code block (i.e. `@{ ... }`).  Try this:

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach(Item c in ViewBag.Items)
    {
        SelectListItem i = new SelectListItem();
        i.Text = c.Name.ToString();
        i.Value = c.SiteID.ToString();
        selectList.Add(new SelectListItem());
    }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Casinos", new SelectList(selectList,"Value","Text"));
}
```

Here's a [quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) for razor syntax.  Also, although you've mentioned this is throw-away code, I'll mention using [view[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878937/why-should-i-use-view-models/4878956#4878956) [models[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160649/729541) anyway, just to be sure you're aware of them.  I can provide a simple example, if you need one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for pointing out the benefits of a ViewModel. I'm aware of the value and benefits, just don't want the added complexity for this exercise.

Comment: @Metaphor Not a problem, I completely understand. Just wanted to be sure.